# How to write from linux device driver to hard drive using DMA

Tags: device, device-driver, linux-device-driver, hard-drive, dma

I can transfer chunks of data from application to device driver but unable to write the interface from device driver to actual harddrive using DMA. Is there any sample code or pointer on this?
Would greatly appreciate your help,

Answer (score 1):

If you've not seen it already, [this](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch15.pdf) is pretty informative.  It's part of [this](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/).

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, But I am actually looking for ways to program the DMA registers on the hard drive controllers.

Comment: @user1360085:  I see.  Well, good luck, then.  I suppose that there might be something to help you in the same book as earlier referenced.  If there is, then I am sure that you'll find it.